# Metabox select arrays is display post id instead of post name in the custom column

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am having a little trouble displaying a post name in a admin column on my custom page in wordpress. I have everything working but when I call the selected item that was chosen from a drop down from a custom metabox it displays the post ID in the admin column instead of the post name.

Here is the code I am using ( to display the columns)

```
add_filter('manage_edit-projects_columns', 'edit_projects_columns');

function edit_projects_columns($columns) {

$columns = array(
    'cb'        => '<input type="checkbox" />',
    'title'     => __( 'Project Title' ),
    'client'    => __( 'Client' ),
    'protype'   => __( 'Project Type' ),
    'featureImage'  => __( 'Project Image' ),   
    );

return $columns;

}
```

To Display the selected fields

```
add_action('manage_projects_posts_custom_column', 'manage_projects_columns', 10, 2);

function manage_projects_columns($column, $post_id, $selected) {
    global $post;
    switch($column) {
        /* Display Column */
    case 'client' :
    /* Get the post meta. */
        $selected = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'a_clients', true);
        if (empty($selected))
            echo __('');
    else
            printf(__( '%s' ), $selected);
        break;

        /* End Display Column */
    /* If displaying the 'genre' column. */
        case 'protype' :
            $terms = get_the_terms($post_id, 'tagwork');
    if (!empty($terms)) {
        $out = array();
        foreach($terms as $term) {
            $out[] = sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url(add_query_arg(array('post_type' => $post->post_type, 'tagwork' => $term->slug), 'edit.php')),
            esc_html(sanitize_term_field('tagwork', $term->name, $term->term_id, 'tagwork', 'tagwork'))
        );
        }
        echo join(', ', $out);
    } else {
        _e('');
    }
    break;

        case 'featureImage' :
        $column = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'featureImage');

    if (empty($contact))
                echo __('');
    else
                printf(__('%s'), $contact);
    break;

    default :
    break;
    }
}
```

The selected field I am having trouble with is client

```
/* Display Column */
case 'client' :
/* Get the post meta. */
$selected = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'a_clients', true);
if (empty($selected))
    echo __('');
else
    printf(__('%s'), $selected);
break;
```

It is displaying the post ID instead of the post name.How would I go about fixing this?

Extra Note: The column is pulling the client information from a drop down menu on a projects page. The menu is pulling the titles from any new client I add to the client page. This way I can assign a project to a specific client.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `$selected` is being assigned the value of the `a_clients` meta value, which seems to be a `post_id`. You need to use this `post_id` to fetch the `WP_Post` for the client and then use the `post_title` property to print out the proper title. You can leave out the `else` since it's just an empty string.

```
/* Display Column */
case 'client' :
    /* Get the post meta. */
    $client_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'a_clients', true );
    // Will be true if a_clients is not "" or 0 
    if ( !empty($client_id) ){
        // Get the post for the client_id
        $client = get_post($client_id);
        // If we have a title, print it out, else just use the ID
        printf( __( '%s' ), !empty($client->post_title)? $client->post_title : $client_id);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: I have no clue why I did not see that. Thank you!